# Apache Ignite Thin Client Events

Tags: ignite, thin-client

I am trying to build an apache ignite thinclient poc and am able to connect to a cluster and also read the data using a ScanQuery. But am stuck at creating a Listener for any cache updates. I looked through but could not find anything for thin clients. Does ignite thin client even support listening on cache updates? How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, thin clients don't support Continuous Queries. You'll need to use a thick client to get that functionality.